# Flutter: why using controllers instead of registering event listeners in widgets directly?

Tags: flutter, dart, controller, widget

Sometimes having to create controller, registering it in widget and then registering listener in controller looks like overengineering. I'm trying to understand why Flutter Team decided to go this path for some widgets, i.e. for text field, list view, while for others, i.e. for button widgets we can simply register onPress listener right in the widget itself, which obviously is easier and requires less boilerplate code.

Any reason why having controllers is a better thing compared to simple event listeners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controllers are used to store state higher up in the widget tree so a parent widget can both react to it as well as change it.

In the case of a text field, it wouldn’t be convenient to have a callback when a user presses a key and then have the parent construct the new text that should be displayed and rebuild the text field with that. (And it is not just key presses because you can paste text as well.) So the text field stores the text, so it always knows what to display and the onChange callback can report the whole text after the user changes it.

But then you might want to change to text from the parent as well. They could have made it such that the parent would have to rebuild the text field with a new text in such as case. However, for some use cases where you don’t just want to overwrite what a user typed, the parent would have to stored the text as well. Which would duplicate the state.

In the end it is simpler to have the controller own the state (the text) and allow both the parent and text field to change it and to read it.

For a ScrollController the situation is similar: both the scroll view and its parent might want the change the scroll position. And both might want to read it (surely the scroll view does).

Another advantage of the controller pattern is that the “parent” could be several widgets higher and you’d only have to pass a single controller through the intermediate widgets instead of several callbacks and several pieces of data.

Comment: I see. So basically what you are saying is - when we need to pass information in both directions - from and to widget - controller is used - as it has this "full-duplex connection" with its widget. While when only widget needs to report some information - such as when a button is pressed, event listener is good enough.

Comment: I’d say when the state of a widget is complex or the interactions with it rich or frequent, using a controller pattern is more convenient than callbacks and rebuilding the widget with new data.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because of 1st principal of S.O.L.I.D. which means `single responsibility`. Each object `should be` responsible for its own specific functionality.  `TextField` serves text input,  `ListView` serves item browsing nothing more. If you need some other (optional) data you need `to ask` someone other who responsible for it. Indeed, it is a controller.

From other side this approach gives some flexibility. You may change controller on runtime.